# Types of SNMPvarbind fields in Scapy

Tags: networking, snmp, scapy

I'm trying to create custom SNMP-trap.

> send(IP(dst="10.152.1.81", src="10.152.1.100")/UDP(sport=55555,
>   dport=3338)/SNMP(version=1 , community= 'test' ,
>   PDU=SNMPtrapv2(id=14452,
>   varbindlist=[SNMPvarbind(oid='1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0',value=6100)])))

In Wireshark:

> ...
>   Value (Integer32): 6100
>   ...

In hex it looks:

> 02 02 17 d4

Where '02 02' is value type (Integer32).
But i need to change value type to

> Value (Timeticks): 6100

Hex:

> 43 04 17 d4

Yes, i can change it using hex:

```
e=IP(dst="10.152.1.81", src="10.152.1.100")/UDP(sport=55555, dport=3338)/SNMP(version=1 , community= 'test' , PDU=SNMPtrapv2(id=14452, varbindlist=[SNMPvarbind(oid='1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0',value=6100)]))
>>> str(e)
"E\x00\x00E\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x11b\xc3\n\x98\x01d\n\x98\x01Q\xd9\x03\r\n\x001T\xf10'\x02\x01\x01\x04\x04test\xa7\x1c\x02\x028t\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x000\x100\x0e\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x02\x01\x01\x03\x00\x02\x02\x17\xd4"
>>> c = "E\x00\x00E\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x11b\xc3\n\x98\x01d\n\x98\x01Q\xd9\x03\r\n\x001T\xf10'\x02\x01\x01\x04\x04test\xa7\x1c\x02\x028t\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x000\x100\x0e\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x02\x01\x01\x03\x00\x43\x04\x17\xd4"
>>> send IP(c)
```

But this method is too difficult when i use 'large' traps.

Whether there is a another method to change this type, or where i can find all possible fields(maybe value_timeticks, value_oid, etc) for SNMPvarbind in Scapy?

Sorry for my google-english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the class `ASN1_TIME_TICKS`

it should look like this:

```
varbindlist=[SNMPvarbind(oid=ASN1_OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"),value=ASN1_TIME_TICKS(6100))]
```

<del>http://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.2.0/classscapy_1_1asn1_1_1asn1_1_1ASN1__TIME__TICKS.html</del>